# Trying to remove numbers bigger than my target number

Tags: java

I'm trying to fill an array with numbers from a file and I can't seem to figure out how to remove numbers larger than my target "D".

Here is the code where I'm having the problem

```
public static void populateMatrix(int[] s){
    File input = new File("set2.txt");
    int value;

    try{
        Scanner inf = new Scanner(input);

        for(int i = 0; i < s.length ; i++){
            value = inf.nextInt();
            if(value > D){
                //Don't know what to add here.
            }//if
            else{
                s[i] = value;
            }//else

        }//for
    }//try

    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}//PopulateMatrix
```

Comment: What happens if you do nothing? If the value is not one you want in your array, don't add it into the array and just let it get dropped.

Comment: Well I've got that part fixed. Now I have a new problem the array is getting filled with 0s because the array is set to 53 I don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't want empty space into your array I'll do this :

```
public static void populateMatrix(int[] s){
    File input = new File("set2.txt");
    int value;

    try{
    Scanner inf = new Scanner(input);

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length ;){
        value = inf.nextInt();
        if(value <= D){
            s[i] = value;
            i++;
        }
    }//for
    }//try

    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}//PopulateMatrix
```

Answer (score 2):

Arguably, you could just keep pulling an int using a while loop and then assign it when it qualifies.

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.length ; i++){
    value = inf.nextInt();
    while(value > D){
        value = inf.nextInt();
    }
    s[i] = value;
 }
```

Obviously, if you run out of ints to get next of, this will throw an error, but there wasn't any checking before so it'll still be up to you to error-check regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Read next number if `value >D`

or

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.length i++;){
    value = inf.nextInt();
    if(value <= D){
        s[i] = value;
    }
```